# Show/Hide button in repeater based on bool result of function

Tags: c#, eval, repeater

I have a function that checks the database to see if the current user is a primary user (this value is called "Type" in the database and is a bit value of 1 or 0--a primary user has a Type of 1) and if the address in the address listing is a billing address (which is represented by the "IsBilling" value in the database which is also a bit value of 0 or 1. If the address is a billing address, then the IsBilling value is 1. If the address is a shipping address, then the value is 0).

What I am trying to do is to show the edit address button ONLY to those users who are primary users--otherwise, it should be hidden. I don't want to hide the edit button for the shipping addresses, though.

Right now, I can't seem to target the billing address--Whenever I set the bool variable ShowButton to true or false, this ends up applying to all the edit buttons.

I checked the SELECT query in the database and it does bring back all the correct values based on the current user id. But I am not sure why I can't choose when to show/hide the button for the Billing Address.

This is the function:

```
    protected bool ShowButton(int UserId)
    {
        bool ShowButton = false;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Type, IsBilling FROM CustomerUsers INNER JOIN Addresses ON uidUser = Addresses.UserId WHERE uidUser = @UserId", cn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", UserId));

                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt16(reader["Type"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt16(reader["IsBilling"]) == 1)
                        {
                                   ShowButton = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString() + "<br />");

        }
        return ShowButton;
    }
```

This is the repeater with the EditAddressButton:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ShipToAddressList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ShipToAddressList_ItemCommand" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="entry aEntry" >
                                                <div class="caption">
                                                    <h2><asp:Literal ID="AddressCaption" runat="server" Text='<%#((bool)Eval("IsBilling"))?"Billing Address":"Shipping Address" %>'></asp:Literal></h2>
                                                    <span class="links">
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="EditAddressButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddressId")%>' Visible = '<%# ShowButton(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("UserId"))) %>' CommandName="Edit" CssClass="link"><asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="/app_themes/cartbuttons/btn_Edit.jpg" runat="server" /></asp:LinkButton><%-- --%>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteAddressButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddressId")%>' CommandName="Del" Visible='<%#!((bool)Eval("IsBilling")) %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this address?');" CssClass="link" ><asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="/app_themes/cartbuttons/btn_Delete.jpg" runat="server" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="address">
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="Address" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'></asp:Literal>
                                                    <br /><asp:Literal ID="phoneAndEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# getPhoneAndEmail(AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Eval("AddressId"))) %>'></asp:Literal>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="buttons">
                                                    <br /><br />
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="PickAddressButton" runat="server" SkinID="Button" CommandName="Pick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddressId")%>' CssClass="button"><asp:Image ID="ImagePick" runat="server" ImageUrl="/app_themes/cartbuttons/btn_Ship.jpg" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </div>                                        
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: should this line be changed to actually set the button visibility 
if (Convert.ToInt16(reader["Type"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt16(reader["IsBilling"]) == 1)
                        {
                                   ShowButton = false;
                        } this seems quite odd the recursive nature of the ShowButton call

Comment: Yes, you are correct but change this does not seem to fix the problem I'm having.

Comment: you are not doing anything from what the code appears but just calling a recursive method.. where in the code are you calling and or assigning the button enabled or disabled.. ?

Comment: I am calling the ShowButton function in the Visible property of the EditAddressButton

Comment: I see now..sorry I didn't scroll over far enough.. are you debugging the code..? but a break point there and tell me what you see.. are you getting any of the buttons to work..? or none..? I wonder if you are evaluating the wrong thing..

Comment: What happens is, while inside the while part of the ShowButton function, the correct true/false values are displayed (1 true, 5 false). But at the end of the function, the ShowButton bool variable is always set to false (or true if I change it to equal true inside the while loop)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60037/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-sara-dejaneiro).